# PHP pack/unpack float in big endian byte order

Tags: php, floating-point, endianness, pack

How can I pack/unpack floats in big endian byte order with php?
I got this far with an unpack function, but I'm not sure if this would even work.

```
function unpackFloat ($float) {
    $n = unpack ('Nn');
    $n = $n['n'];

    $sign = ($n >> 31);
    $exponent = ($n >> 23) & 0xFF;
    $fraction = $n & 0x7FFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP 7.2 introduced the option to pack floating point numbers with big endian byte order directly:

```php
// float
$bytes = pack('G', 3.1415);

// double precision float
$bytes = pack('E', 3.1415);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Answer (score 5):

After thinking about it for a while I found a pretty easy solution, to use the opposite byte order from the one `pack('f')` uses.

`unpack`

```
unpack('fdat', strrev(substr($data, 0, 4)));
```

`pack`

```
strrev(pack('f', $data));
```